# Given the coordinate vector, how can I find the vector with respect to a particular basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the coordinate vector $v_{|B}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$, how can I find the vector $v$ with respect to the basis $B=\{1+x, x\}$?

Comment: $$v = 1(1 + x) + (-1)x$$

Comment: Go back to basic definitions: What does it mean for $v_B$ to be the coordinates of $v$?